# I'm currently trying to clear the input field after the task has been added to the array

Tags: javascript, input-field

I'm currently trying to clear the input field after the task has been added to the array. i know it will be very simple but for the life of me i can't seem to figure out the solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

### Here is my code:

***HTML:***

```
<body>

 <form action="#" method="post" id="theForm">
 <fieldset><legend>Enter an Item To Be Done</legend>
 <div>
 <label for="task">Task</label>
 <input type="text" name="task" id="task" required> 
 </div>
  <div>
 <input type="submit" value="Add It!" id="submit" value="reset form">
 </div>
 <div id="output"></div>
 </fieldset>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
 var tasks = []; 
 function addTask() {
 'use strict';

  var task = document.getElementById('task');
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  var message = '';

   if (task.value) {
   tasks.push(task.value);
   message = '<h2>To-Do</h2>';
   message +=  '<ol><li>'; 
   message +=  tasks.join('</li><li>'); 
   message +=  '</li></ol>';

   output.innerHTML = message;

   } 
    return false;
   } 

   function init() {
    'use strict';
    document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = addTask 

    frm.submit(); 
    frm.reset();

    return false;
    } 
    window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just clear the value of the task field by  adding task.value='';

Here is the full working code.

**HTML**

```
 <form action="#" method="post" id="theForm">
     <fieldset><legend>Enter an Item To Be Done</legend>
     <div>
     <label for="task">Task</label>
     <input type="text" name="task" id="task" required> 
     </div>
      <div>
     <input type="submit" value="Add It!" id="submit" value="reset form">
     </div>
     <div id="output"></div>
     </fieldset>
     </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
     var tasks = []; 
     function addTask() {
     'use strict';

      var task = document.getElementById('task');
      var output = document.getElementById('output');
      var message = '';

       if (task.value) {
       tasks.push(task.value);
       message = '<h2>To-Do</h2>';
       message +=  '<ol><li>'; 
       message +=  tasks.join('</li><li>'); 
       message +=  '</li></ol>';
     task.value='';
       output.innerHTML = message;

       } 
        return false;
       } 

       function init() {
        'use strict';
        document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = addTask 

        frm.submit(); 
        frm.reset();

        return false;
        } 
        window.onload = init;
```

Answer (score 0):

well for me it looks like you need add only 1 string

```
output.innerHTML = message;
task.value = '';
```

Comment: Yep!
that worked a treat. As you can probably tell i'm only just starting javascript.
Thanks for that!